# Menu item hover animate all other items not the first one?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Using jQuery or CSS or combination of both for menu item hover animation.

I need help with menu items. E.g. Mouseover on one of the menu items, all the other menu items get hover animation but not the one with mouseover.

I have CSS animation below that I would like to use with the requirements above.

I also have jQuery code and the logic work fine with using "text-decoration", "line-through". But line-through is very poor CSS, I'd like to combine the below CSS and jQuery to achieve the above.

This is for WordPress menu items.

```js
jQuery(".menu-menu-container ul li").hover(function() { // Mouse over
  jQuery(this).siblings().stop().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
  jQuery(this).parent().siblings().stop().css("text-decoration", "none");
}, function() { // Mouse out
  jQuery(this).siblings().stop().css("text-decoration", "none");
  jQuery(this).parent().siblings().stop().css("text-decoration", "none");
});
```

```css
.overlay-content ul li a:hover:after,
.overlay-content ul li a:focus:after,
.overlay-content ul li a:active:after {
  width: 40%;
  background: #000;
}

.overlay-content ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 2%;
  margin-top: 3.2%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: .35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Help</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like to combine the CSS and jQuery to achieve the hover affect/animation above.

Comment: Some HTML might be useful too

Comment: Hi RoKo

Just a simple html for a menu items.  

<div class="menu-menu-container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Help</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

Comment: Added your HTML snippet to your Question

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding css styles in jQuery itself, I would add and remove classes based on event. It gives you more power to use CSS features. Something like this instead,

```
jQuery(".menu-menu-container ul li").hover(function() { // Mouse over
    jQuery(this).addClass("hovered");
    jQuery(this).siblings("li").addClass("notHovered")
  }, function() { // Mouse out
    jQuery(this).siblings().stop().removeClass("notHovered"); 
    jQuery(this).removeClass("hovered")
  });
```

and CSS:

```
.overlay-content ul li a:hover:after, .overlay-content ul li a:focus:after, .overlay-content ul li a:active:after {
  width: 40%;
  background: #000;
}

.menu-menu-container ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 2%;
    margin-top: 3.2%;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: .35s;
}

.menu-menu-container{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0 7.5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

.menu-menu-container li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif


}

.notHovered{
  filter: blur(2px);

}

li.hovered{
  border-top-color: white
}

.menu-menu-container a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.menu-menu-container li, .menu-menu-container *{
  transition: 1s;

}
```

Here's a very basic [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdxjGM) showing what I mean. It's just to give you an idea....Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Eric McWinNEr

Thanks for your support. This looks great and it work how exactly it should. I'd like to have the border line through the menu items instead of the blur effect. And the lose the border that appears on the menu item that mouseover. 

I look forward to hearing from you...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JS at all! Simply set the styles on UL hover, and than separately on each A hover:

```css
.menu-menu {
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  /* Relative, we can now use absolute elements inside */
  position: relative;
}

.menu-menu a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: .35s;
}

.menu-menu:hover a:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-menu a:hover:after,
.menu-menu a:focus:after,
.menu-menu a:active:after {
  width: 0%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I don't know how to thank you! I've been trying to fix with JS and CSS and it never worked! Awesome and if I can leave a review or feedback for you please let me know. @Roko C. Buljan :)